# connectivity module doesn't work using Nativescript

Tags: android, typescript, nativescript, multipeer-connectivity

I follow [this](https://docs.nativescript.org/ns-framework-modules/connectivity) tutorial, and write in app.component.ts this code.

```
    export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
    isConnection: boolean;
    constructor() {}
    ngOnInit() {
        const myConnectionType = getConnectionType();
        switch (myConnectionType) {
            case connectionType.none:
                this.isConnection= false;
                dialogs.confirm({
                    message: "Please, check Wifi",
                    okButtonText: "OK",
                }).then(result => {
                    console.log("Dialog result: " + result);
                });
                break;
            case connectionType.wifi:
                this.isConnection= true
                break;
            case connectionType.mobile:
                this.isConnection= false;
                dialogs.confirm({
                    message: "Please, check Wifi",
                    okButtonText: "OK",
                }).then(result => {
                    console.log("Dialog result: " + result);
                });
                break;
            case connectionType.ethernet:
                this.isConnection= false;
                dialogs.confirm({
                    message: "Please, check Wifi",
                    okButtonText: "OK",
                }).then(result => {
                    console.log("Dialog result: " + result);
                });
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

I don't understand why doesn't work when I disconnect WiFi?

In app.component.html

```
<page-router-outlet></page-router-outlet>
```

In AndroidManifest/xml I put `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>`

Have you any idea please?

Comment: Can you please post more info, which device / OS version you are testing this against? What you mean by it doesn't work, can you try logging it instead of alert. It may be too early to show alert on app component's onInit.

Comment: is it possible for you to create a playground? As @Manoj mentioned it would be helpful if you specify device/os version as well.

Answer (score 1):

Answer to your question " why doesn't work when I disconnect WiFi?" us "`You have to monitor the connection`". In your code you are just checking the connection type on app load but you have to **monitor** that as well in case you want to check when wi-fi is dicsonnected.

```
ngOnInit() {
connectivity.startMonitoring((newConnectionType: number) => {
      switch (newConnectionType) {
        case connectivity.connectionType.none:
          this._userService.connectionType = AppConstants.INT_CONN_NONE;
          console.log('Connection type changed to none.');
          break;
        case connectivity.connectionType.wifi:
          this._userService.connectionType = AppConstants.INT_CONN_WIFI;
          console.log('Connection type changed to WiFi.');
          break;
        case connectivity.connectionType.mobile:
          this._userService.connectionType = AppConstants.INT_CONN_MOBILE;
          console.log('Connection type changed to mobile.');
          break;
        default:
          break;
      }
    });
}
```